# How i can do a multiple dynamic popup

Tags: php

This code would complete the table, that work find. The problem with this is that when i can show a dynamic popup only work in the first row but in anyelse don't work

```
<tr>
<td><img src="../mysql/img/<?php echo $fila['imagen'];?>" class="logoempresa" alt="Logo empresa"></td> 
<?php $fila['id'];?> 
<td><?php echo $fila['empresa'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['puesto'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['jornada'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['salario'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['zona'];?></td>
<td>
    <div class="popup-flex">
        <button id="popup-btn">Click Me</button>
    </div>

    <div id="popup-wrapper" class="popup-container">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <span id="close">&times;</span>
            <p class="observaciones"><?php echo $fila['observaciones'];?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: do not use `ID` attributes - they must be unique. Use the `event` and `event.target` to identify any elements that invokes the `popup` and use that to create the popup. If you can add some of the rendered code ( ie: source code view ) of the table - not necessarily all of it - it will be easier to illustrate the point

Comment: From the `event.target` you can navigate through the DOM using parent/child/sibling selectors ( depending where you need to go )  - when you find the relevant `popup-wrapper` element open the popup

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<button id="<?= $fila['id'];?> " class="popup-btn">Click Me</button>
```

jquery

```
$('.popup-btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let id = $(this).attr('id')
    //do magic
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla Javascript you might try like this. Remove the ID attributes or convert to `dataset` versions such as `data-id="popup-wrapper"` rather than `id="popup-wrapper"` and use the `click` event triggered by the button to locate that element in the DOM tree. From that point you can navigate `up` the DOM tree and query once more to find the POPUP. Once you have identified the popup - open it or do something.. here I just toggle a className.

All the PHP tags below have been removed simply to facilitate the snippet/demo...

```js
const clickhandler=function(e){
  let popup=this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('[data-id="popup-wrapper"]');
      popup.classList.toggle('popped');
      /* Open the popup... sing and dance! */
};


document.querySelectorAll('.popup-flex > [data-id="popup-btn"]').forEach( bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',clickhandler))
```

```css
.popped{border:2px solid red;}
td{border:1px solid grey}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//placekitten.com/100/100" class="logoempresa" alt="Logo empresa"></td> 
            <td>$fila['empresa']</td>
            <td>$fila['puesto']</td>
            <td>$fila['jornada']</td>
            <td>$fila['salario']</td>
            <td>$fila['zona']</td>
            <td>
                <div class="popup-flex">
                    <button data-id="popup-btn">Click Me</button>
                </div>

                <div data-id="popup-wrapper" class="popup-container">
                    <div class="popup-content">
                        <span data-id="close">&times;</span>
                        <p class="observaciones">$fila['observaciones']</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//placekitten.com/100/100" class="logoempresa" alt="Logo empresa"></td> 
            <td>$fila['empresa']</td>
            <td>$fila['puesto']</td>
            <td>$fila['jornada']</td>
            <td>$fila['salario']</td>
            <td>$fila['zona']</td>
            <td>
                <div class="popup-flex">
                    <button data-id="popup-btn">Click Me</button>
                </div>

                <div data-id="popup-wrapper" class="popup-container">
                    <div class="popup-content">
                        <span data-id="close">&times;</span>
                        <p class="observaciones">$fila['observaciones']</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td><img src="//placekitten.com/100/100" class="logoempresa" alt="Logo empresa"></td> 
            <td>$fila['empresa']</td>
            <td>$fila['puesto']</td>
            <td>$fila['jornada']</td>
            <td>$fila['salario']</td>
            <td>$fila['zona']</td>
            <td>
                <div class="popup-flex">
                    <button data-id="popup-btn">Click Me</button>
                </div>

                <div data-id="popup-wrapper" class="popup-container">
                    <div class="popup-content">
                        <span data-id="close">&times;</span>
                        <p class="observaciones">$fila['observaciones']</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```